# Cloudflare caching: Cache everything and ignore a folder in name /page/X

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I site has lots of pages, /page/1, /page/2, /page/3 etc.

These pages has exactly the same JS code that checks the URL and load a JSON file, like /json/1.json, /json/2.json, /json/3.json etc.

If I use cache everything for [/page/*], and a user visits 3 different ones and CloudFlare currently holds no caches, my server will serve all 3 and it will only be on the second visit that a cached version will be served.

I'm looking for a way to kind of "ignore" the page number in this example and if a user visits /page/1 and then /page/2 on a server with no cache to be hit, only /page/1 will load from the server and /page/2 will load from the CDN cache.

I've seen the "ignore query stings" option, which seems like what I'm looking for, although for SEO-purposes, I want to use folders in the urls (/page/1) and not query strings (/page/?page=1).

Is this possible with Page Rules, Caching Rules perhaps when using workers, and if so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to create a [Cloudflare URL rewrite rule](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/url-rewrite/create-dashboard) to convert all those incoming URLs into a single URL before it is passed into Cloudflare's other products. For example rewrite all `/json/*` to `/json/json1.json`. Then Cloudflare would always request `/json/json1.json` from your server whenever a `/json/*` request comes in, and if it already has the `/json/json1.json` response cached then it would use the cached version instead of hitting your server.